# xsl-stylesheet or xslt-styleshhet, one and the same?

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

this might sound rather stupid, but I couldn't really find an answer in my books.

Some books use the term "XSLT-Stylesheet" while others tend to use "XSL-Stylesheet" and some use both terms. I can't really figure out the difference between both terms, to me it seems like they are exactly the same. Am I correct here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Stylesheet_Language):

> Sometimes XSL refers to XSLT: this
>   usage is best avoided. However, "xsl"
>   is used both as the conventional
>   namespace prefix for the XSLT
>   namespace, and as the conventional
>   filename suffix for files containing
>   XSLT stylesheet modules

So yes, often XSLT-Stylesheet and XSL-Stylesheet are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is part of XSL, so both is correct but XSLT-Stylesheet is more precise.